# How does the parity of $n$ affect the properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Does the parity of the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ affect its structure/properties? As in, does it make a difference if $n$ is even or odd?

Comment: What kinds of properties specifically are you interested in?

Comment: There are many differences between even and odd dimensions, but without more details it is not clear what direction you want answers. Examples: Complex/symplectic structures do not exist on odd dimensional spaces. Contact structures do not exist on even dimensional spaces.

Comment: Even dimensional manifolds are the basic framework for symplectic geometry, odd for contact geometry.

Comment: This question seems a little broad. There are all kinds of differences one can point to. For example, the one-point compactifications $S^n$ behave differently: the odd-dimensional ones have non-vanishing vector fields. (Also: why is number theory a tag, precisely?)

Comment: I was originally thinking of the result that a polynomial of odd degree has at least one real root. In a certain sense, the structure of the object depends on the space it is defined in.This got me curious about the relationship between the number of a dimension and the types of structures it can support.I was asking the question in regard to the tags on the question; i.e, how does dimension of space come up in Linear Algebra, Topology, etc.

Number theory tagged specifically because I was curious if the number of the dimension being composite or prime would have any impact.

Answer (score 21):

Let me try to focus the question as follows: Suppose you wake up in a dark and empty space. Which properties can help you decide whether the space is even or odd-dimensional?

In the context of wave propagation, there is the fundamental difference that [Huygens principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) is only valid in odd-dimensional space, see [Wave Propagation in Even and Odd Dimensional Spaces](http://static.stevereads.com/papers_to_read/wave_propagation_in_even_and_odd_dimensional_spaces.pdf). Sharply defined wavefronts need an odd number of spatial dimensions, in even-dimensional space the wavefront decays with a long tail. (The study of this difference goes back to Volterra and Hadamard.)

So to test for even/odd dimensionality you only need to shout in empty space. If you hear an echo you live in an even number of spatial dimensions.

Comment: In odd dimensions $-1$ is  orientation reversing.

Comment: The situation is a little bit more complicated. For instance, Huyghens principle does not apply in $1$-space dimension, although $1$ is odd.

Comment: @DenisSerre --- indeed, the case $n = 1$ is special because a pulse has only one path to take, so the interference that produces the sharp wavefront does not happen; thanks for noting/correcting.

Comment: This sounds like a great premise for a new Saw-like horror movie. A group of strangers wake up in a dark, empty space. They need to determine the dimension of the ambient space, but their time is running out!

Answer (score 4):

The [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) states that there is no nonvanishing continuous tangent vector field on *even-dimensional* spheres.

Answer (score 4):

If the dimension of a vector space is odd, then all (orientation-preserving) rotations in odd dimensions fix some axis.  Many of the differences between even-dimensional and odd-dimensional geometry relate to this fact.  For example,

- The lack of symplectic structure in odd dimensions follows from the Lie-algebra version of the above statement: all odd-dimensional antisymmetric maps are degenerate.
- The $-1$ map doesn't fix any axis, so it cannot be orientation-preserving in odd dimensions.
- [Synge's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synge%27s_theorem) states that if $M$ is compact, Riemannian, and has positive sectional curvature, then there is a conclusion which depends on the pairity of its dimension.  The proof makes essential use of the above fact. (See Lemma 3.8 in "Riemannian Geometry" by do Carmo.)