# Does the primality of the number of dimensions affect its properties?

Tags: prime-numbers

Motivated by [How does the parity of a dimension affect its properties?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/311778/11260) I dare to ask the following question (with thanks to my colleague Vedran Dunjko): We happen to live in a world of prime dimensionality. Is that special? Are there properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that only apply to $n$ a prime integer?

Comment: For one, various representation theory questions are much easier if the dimension is a prime number. No nontrivial imprimitive groups, etc etc.

Comment: Quite obviously, there seems to be some kind of irreducibility attached to real linear spaces of prime dimension : such a space can't be isomorphic to  $ \mathbb{R}^{m}\otimes\mathbb{R}^{n} $ with both  $ m $  and  $ n $ greater than  $ 1 $ .

Comment: I can hardly wait for "does having a Fibonacci number of dimensions affect its properties?"